# Function returns an empty array rather than it being populated

Tags: ios, swift, function, nsarray, nsurl

I'm attempting to load data from a JSON file to be used inside my tableview.  Nevertheless, when I call this function in viewdidload the array I want to fill the data with contains no data and returns an empty array.

```
class CompanyModel {

func getJSON() -> NSMutableArray() {

let companyArray: NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray()

let requestURL: NSURL = NSURL(string: "http://localhost/Companies/JSON.php")!
let urlRequest: NSMutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: requestURL)
let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()

let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(urlRequest) { <- does not enter bracket?
    (data, response, error) -> Void in

    let httpResponse = response as! NSHTTPURLResponse
    let statusCode = httpResponse.statusCode

    if (statusCode == 200) {
        print("Everyone is fine, file downloaded successfully.")

        do{

            let json = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options:.AllowFragments)

            if let companies = json["companies"] as? [[String: AnyObject]] {

                for company in companies {

                    if let name = company["name"] as? String,
                        let phoneNumber = company["phone_number"] as? String,
                        let website = company["website"] as? String,
                        let email = company["email"] as? String,
                        let address = company["address"] as? String

                    {
                    let company = CompanyModel()

                        company.name = name
                        company.phoneNumber = phoneNumber
                        company.website = website
                        company.email = email
                        company.address = address
                    }
                    companyArray.addObject(company)
                    print(companyArray)
                }
            }
        } catch {
            print("Error with Json: \(error)")
        }

    }
    print(companyArray) <- array is populated
}
print(companyArray) <- array is empty
task.resume()
return companyArray
}
}
```

When I run a debug session, it seems it does not enter the bracket where I've stated above.  Instead, it jumps straight to returning the function which then returns an empty array.  I believe no data is fetched from the JSON file but I'm not too sure why.

Comment: try printing your json, do you get valid data? Just making sure.
also, if you can share your Json data, it might be easier to answer. As "companies" might not be the immediate key of json, it might be a key of a key in json.

Comment: Print your json data and check its valid json or not

Answer (score 0):

Your second `print(companyArray)` code runs before the call can return with data from the server as request is done as a background task. You should write `return companyArray` inside the success code else `return` empty an array in case of failure.

Answer (score 0):

In your code you have created a data task, which runs on different thread.

```
    print(companyArray) <- this one is after request returns a response
}
print(companyArray) <- this comes before the array is populated
task.resume() <- And here is where you start the data task
return companyArray
```

You can change your logic to return companyArray in completion of your method.

```
    print(companyArray) <- and for the love of God, don't put return here! 
}
print(companyArray) <- this comes before the array is populated
task.resume() <- And here is where you start the data task
return companyArray
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code `localhost` is creating a issue and you will be getting `response` as `nil`. So, it's better to `print(data)`, `print(response)`, `print(error)` before checking anything. Just to check use this URL : `https://httpbin.org/get` and later on please replace your `localhost` with `IP` or `domain` in your URL.

Here is the updating code for the above:

```
func getWebServiceWithURL(strUrl: String, completionHandler: (NSDictionary?, NSError?) -> ()) -> (){

    let getTask = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(NSURL(string: strUrl)!) { (responseData, _, error) -> Void in

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in

            do{
                if responseData != nil{

                    let json = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(responseData!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.AllowFragments) as? NSDictionary

                    if let parseJSON = json {

                        // Parsed JSON
                        completionHandler(parseJSON, nil)
                    }
                    else {
                        // Woa, okay the json object was nil, something went worng. Maybe the server isn't running?
                        let jsonStr = NSString(data: responseData!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)

                        #if DEBUG
                            print("Error could not parse JSON: \(jsonStr)")
                        #endif
                    }
                }else{

                    completionHandler(nil, error)
                }

            }catch let error as NSError{

                print(error.localizedDescription)
                completionHandler(nil, error)
            }
        })
    }

    getTask.resume()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A part from the [doc of NSURLSession](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLSession_class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSURLSession/dataTaskWithRequest:):

> Like most networking APIs, the NSURLSession API is highly
>   **asynchronous**. It returns data to your app in one of two ways,
>   depending on the methods you call:
>
> ```
> To a completion handler block that is called when a transfer finishes successfully or with an error.
>
> By calling methods on the session’s delegate as data is received and when the transfer is complete.
> ```

and A part from your code:

```
   print(companyArray) <- array is populated
}
print(companyArray) <- array is empty
```

You get `companyArray` populated inside your completion handler once the asynchronous process completes, and it is empty outside the completion handler because the code :

```
print(companyArray) <- array is empty
```

runs very next to this line:

```
let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(urlRequest) {
```

and the completion handler is not yet evaluated. Consume completion handler to get actual results.

Answer (score 0):

Your `return companyArray` getting called before response is come from server. so you shouldn't make a method with return type like array! You should take `companyArray` as public variable or instance variable and you can set it's value from completion block of webservice call and can use where needed.

Hope this will help :)